# How to create an array to populate the data

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php

$CountrySQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM report_adherence_daily";
$CountryResult = mysql_query($CountrySQL);
$Country_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($CountryResult); 

if(mysql_num_rows($CountryResult) > 0) { ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawAnnotations);

    function drawAnnotations() {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
<?php 

$htmlOutput    = array();
$CountryResult = mysql_query($CountrySQL) or die (mysql_error());
$colsToDisplay = mysql_num_rows($CountryResult)+1;
echo "data.addColumn('string', '<nobr>Week Commencing:');";
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($CountryResult)) {
echo "data.addColumn('number', '{$row['Country']}');";
}
$colsDifference = count($htmlOutput) % $colsToDisplay;
if($colsDifference) {
 while($colsDifference < $colsToDisplay) {           
 $htmlOutput[] = '';          
 $colsDifference++;      } }
$htmlOutput = array_chunk($htmlOutput, $colsToDisplay);   
foreach($htmlOutput as $currRow) { 
print implode('', $currRow);
}

// Let's find out which Dates there are....
$DateSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM report_adherence_daily WHERE Date >= '".$Date."' AND Date <= '".$DateTo."' ORDER BY Date";
$result = mysql_query($DateSQL) or die (mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$Datez[] = array("Date"=>$row["Date"]);
}

// Now  sort out the unique Departments and make an array out of them
$array = array_unique($Datez, SORT_REGULAR);

// Loop through the above array so it makes one query for each separate Department.
foreach($array as $item) {
$AddAnother = "";
$DateSQL = "SELECT Country, Date, format(((sum(Duration)/sum(Scheduled))*100),2) AS Percentage FROM report_adherence_daily WHERE Country = '".$row['Country']."' Date '".$item['Date']."' GROUP BY Country, Date";
$DateResult = mysql_query($DateSQL);
$Date_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($DateResult); 

if(mysql_num_rows($DateResult) > 0) {
if($Country_num_rows > $Date_num_rows) {
$ValuesToAdd =  ($Country_num_rows-$Date_num_rows);
for ($i = 0; $i < $ValuesToAdd; $i++) {
$AddAnother = $AddAnother."0,";
}
} else { $AddAnother = ""; }
?>
data.addRows([
<?php
$htmlOutput    = array();
$DateResult = mysql_query($DateSQL) or die (mysql_error());
$colsToDisplay = mysql_num_rows($DateResult)+1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($DateResult)) {
if(!empty($row["Percentage"])) {    
$Percentage = $row["Percentage"];
} else {
$Percentage = "";
}
$htmlOutput[] = "{$Percentage},";
}
$colsDifference = count($htmlOutput) % $colsToDisplay;
if($colsDifference) {
while($colsDifference < $colsToDisplay) {           
$htmlOutput[] = '';          
$colsDifference++;      } }
$htmlOutput = array_chunk($htmlOutput, $colsToDisplay);   
foreach($htmlOutput as $currRow) {     
print "['".$item['Date']."', " . implode(' ', $currRow) . " ".$AddAnother." ], ]);";
} 
?>
<?php } } ?>

var options = {
  curveType: 'function',
  legend: { position: 'right' },
  lineWidth: 3,
  series: {9: {type: 'line', color: 'grey',lineWidth: 5}},
  chartArea : { left: 60, top:30, right:200, height:300,width: 1300, backgroundColor: { stroke: '#000', strokeWidth: 2, fill:'#fff' }  },
  vAxis: { viewWindowMode:'explicit',format:'#,####', viewWindow: {  min:0,max:100 }, textStyle:{color: '#000',fontSize: '12'} },
  backgroundColor: { fill:'#ebf1de', stroke: '#000', strokeWidth: 2, },
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>

<div id="curve_chart" style="width: 800px; height: 400px"></div>

</center>

<?php } ?>
```

I have just been introduce to HTML/PHP do to my knowledge of VBA. I have inherited some code and have made some amendments which is at the start of this post. The data produced originally looked like `

```
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawAnnotations);

    function drawAnnotations() {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', '<nobr>Week Commencing:');data.addColumn('number', '2016-07-04');data.addColumn('number', '2016-07-05');data.addColumn('number', '2016-07-06');data.addColumn('number', '2016-07-07');data.addColumn('number', '2016-07-08');data.addColumn('number', '2016-07-09');
data.addRows([['France', 55.93, 68.16, 64.77, 67.71, 54.83, 97.59,   ], ]);data.addRows([['Germany', 66.61, 64.25, 71.90, 74.68, 78.02, 87.33,   ], ]);data.addRows([['Italy', 62.81, 61.68, 62.01, 62.22, 58.69, 60.23,   ], ]);data.addRows([['Netherlands', 71.61, 60.32, 62.00, 63.98, 57.41,  0, ], ]);data.addRows([['Nordic', 59.46, 65.68, 64.60, 67.24, 63.88,  0, ], ]);data.addRows([['Spain', 63.27, 68.87, 67.67, 69.12, 70.31,  0, ], ]);data.addRows([['UK', 65.30, 68.44, 70.26, 76.11, 74.18, 93.18,   ], ]);
var options = {
  curveType: 'function',
  legend: { position: 'right' },
  lineWidth: 3,
  series: {9: {type: 'line', color: 'grey',lineWidth: 5}},
  chartArea : { left: 60, top:30, right:200, height:300,width: 1300, backgroundColor: { stroke: '#000', strokeWidth: 2, fill:'#fff' }  },
  vAxis: { viewWindowMode:'explicit',format:'#,####', viewWindow: {  min:0,max:100 }, textStyle:{color: '#000',fontSize: '12'} },
  backgroundColor: { fill:'#ebf1de', stroke: '#000', strokeWidth: 2, },
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

I need the country and Date to swap places.

I have managed in the code posted above to move the country for the Addcolumn part.

```
data.addColumn('string', '<nobr>Week Commencing:');data.addColumn('number', 'Italy');data.addColumn('number', 'Spain');data.addColumn('number', 'Germany');data.addColumn('number', 'Nordic');data.addColumn('number', 'France');data.addColumn('number', 'Netherlands');data.addColumn('number', 'UK');
```

but when it comes to the date and percentage data, I cannot work out what is going on

```
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/servicee/public_html/reporting/Paul/MySite/freddie2.php</b> on line <b>339</b><br />
```

Apologies if this in not in the correct format but as I advised, I am new at this

Comment: What is your specific programming question?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I have inherited this code. the question is how do I get the data in the addrow section to populate the date and Percentage data as it did in the original

Comment: [**Amended Code**](https://jsfiddle.net/Ghostie3001/txsn9asw/) this is my amended code which is producing [**`html Debugger Result`**](https://jsfiddle.net/Ghostie3001/oh0n5d7o/). As you can see, the Addcolumn section works but I cannot get the percentages and date to show